# Assign Variable Value to a Range

Tags: excel, vba

I know this is a dumb question. But how can I use a variable value in a range. My Variable **Cells1** **= 13** and my Variable **Cells2 = 26**. I want to assign both of the numbers to a range which is

```
Range("B13:D26")
```

So far, this is my line of code:

```
Sheets("Budget").Range("B" & Cells1, "D" & Cells2)).Select
```

My code gives me error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: VTC as per [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212024/dealing-with-questions-with-obvious-replies)

Answer (score 0):

I think that **")"** is extra in your code. It should be as follow:

```
Sheets("Budget").Range("B" & Cells1, "D" & Cells2).Select
```

Other way, you want to select `Range("B13:D26")`, you can use as follow:

```
Sheets("Budget").Range("B" & Cells1 & ":D" & Cells2).Select
```

Comment: You are not supposed to answer these kind of questions. Please see [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212024/dealing-with-questions-with-obvious-replies)

Comment: Yes Siddharth Rout, thanks for your guideline. I will take care in next time.